# How to handle repeating System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am using `System.Treading.Timer` for `Task` which is checking some server status and setting label. I want to start this timer with button (start and repeat) and stop it after another button push. But I am unable to do that, I tried to play with `AutoResetEvent` object but I have trouble understanding how it works. Below is my code:

```
public class Main{
    Timer StatusWatch;
    int WatchStatusTime = 500;
    AutoResetEvent WatchReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public Main(){
        StatusWatch = new System.Threading.Timer(StatusWatchCallBack, WatchReset,
            Timeout.Infinite, WatchStatusTime);
    }

    private async void StatusWatchCallBack(object state)
    {
        WatchReset.WaitOne();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lblPlcStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ...
                Timer work
                ...
            });
        });

        WatchReset.Set();
    }

    public void  ButtonClick(){
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            client.Disconnect();
            lblConnect.Content = "Connect";
        }
        else 
        { 
            if (client.ConnectTo(plc.IP, plc.Rack, plc.Slot) == 0)
            {
                lblConnect.Content = "Disconnect";
                WatchReset.WaitOne();
            }
                
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to start this timer and how to end it. Is `AutoResetEvent` even usable for this?

Comment: What is the reason for the `Task.Run`? It seems redundant to me. All it does is to invoke the `Dispatcher`. The `Task.Run` is mainly used to offload work to a background thread, and I can't see any such work to exist in the supplied code.

Comment: Is this in Winforms? If so: make your life easier and use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes it is redundant, thank you

Comment: @Fildor WPF and I need Threading.Timer because it is async

Comment: Ok, slightly more complicated. But what is async, here? The "Timer work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop and restart a `System.Threading.Timer` simply by using the [`Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.change) method:

```
StatusWatch.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite); // Stop

StatusWatch.Change(WatchStatusTime, WatchStatusTime); // Restart
```